# Apex base encoding and openssl

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I Have ruby method for creating signature for REST API call.

```
private static String sign_data(String str, String api_secret, bool cgi_escape)
{
String r = Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'),   api_secret, str)).replace('\n','');
cgi_escape ?  CGI.escape(r) : r
return r
}
```

can any one help me getting equivalent apex code? i tried writing the below apex code but couldn't succeed.

```
private static String sign_data(String str, String api_secret, bool cgi_escape)
   {    
    String r =EncodingUtil.base64Encode((OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, api_secret, str)).replace('\n','');
     return r;   
   }
```

Comment: Added as answer to help others. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED : Use the below solution**

```
private static String sign_data(String str, String api_secret){
    String algorithmName = 'HmacSHA1';
    Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, 
    Blob.valueOf(str),      Blob.valueOf(api_secret));
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
}
```